# read.xlsx modifying contents when converting to .csv in R

Tags: r

I need to convert multiple .xlsx file into csv files but the contents of the original .xlsx is modified during conversion.

For example, the starting excel file will look like this

```
   A  B  C  D
1 Foo
2
3           Foo
```

After conversion, the .csv file will contain this

```
   A  B  C  D
1 X1  X2 X3 X4
2 Foo NA NA NA
3 NA  NA NA NA          
4 Na  Na NA Foo
```

How can I convert the .xlsx without any changes made to the contents? I've also read that read.xlsx may have issues with dates. Is there a simple way to convert .xlsx to csv?

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
 PathOut<-"C:/Users/Desktop/New folder/"

  require(openxlsx)
  file_list<-list.files(path = PathOut, pattern='\\.xlsx$')

  x=0
  for (file in file_list) {
    setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/New folder/")
    x<-x+1
    file.xl <- read.xlsx(file,skipEmptyRows = FALSE,skipEmptyCols = FALSE,colNames = FALSE,rowNames = FALSE)
    newname<-paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file),'_',LETTERS[x],'.csv')
    write.csv(file.xl, paste(PathOut,newname),row.names = FALSE)
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Swap your use of `write.csv` to `write.table` so that you can use the `col.names = FALSE` argument. This will stop the `X1 X2 X3 X4` row from appearing. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227243/write-a-data-frame-to-csv-file-without-column-header-in-r/19227265) for more help.

```
require(openxlsx)

PathOut <- getwd()

file_list <- list.files(path = PathOut, pattern = '\\.xlsx$')

x <- 0
for (file in file_list) {
    x <- x+1
    file.xl <- read.xlsx(file, skipEmptyRows = FALSE, skipEmptyCols = FALSE, colNames = FALSE, rowNames = FALSE)
    newname <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file),'_',LETTERS[x],'.csv')
    write.table(file.xl, paste0(PathOut, "/", newname), row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This removes the column names. I also added na='' to remove the NAs but it does not solve the issue. The data contents are still being modified and quotation marks are added to the .csv if the contents of the excel cell is formatted. I read somewhere that it isn't a good idea to use R to convert the xlsx file into .csv because of this issue.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the problem now. I had previously only been viewing the file in RStudio, where such problems did not happen. There is a `quote = FALSE` parameter that can also be added to the `write.table` function but I don't think this is giving you what you want yet. I'll think on it a bit more.